# Google Translator default language

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-translate

I'm trying to implement google transliteration in my website. It's working on all supported Indian languages. But when I select English it shows some error like '**Unsupported language en in targetLangCode array**'. Please help me to resolve this issue. 
This is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    google.load("elements", "1", {
        packages: "transliteration"
    });
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<select id="languageOptions">
<option value="English">English</option>
<option value="Unicode">Unicode</option>
</select>

<select name="langpair" style="height:32px; padding:0; display:none" id="langpair" size="1">

    <option value="HINDI" selected>Hindi</option>
    <option value="BENGALI">BENGALI</option>
    <option value="TELUGU">Telugu</option>
    <option value="MARATHI">Marathi</option>
    <option value="TAMIL">Tamil</option>
    <option value="URDU">Urdu</option>
    <option value="KANNADA">Kannada</option>
    <option value="GUJARATI">Gujarati</option>
    <option value="MALAYALAM">Malayalam</option>
    <option value="PUNJABI">PUNJABI</option>
    <option value="SANSKRIT">SANSKRIT</option>
    <option value="NEPALI">Nepali</option>
    <option value="ARABIC">Arabic</option>
    <option value="SINDHI">Sindhi</option>
</select>
<br/>

<textarea class="form-control" maxlength="160" id="message" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<hr>

<br/>
<script>
$('#languageOptions).change(function() {
if($(this).val() == 'Unicode') {
$('#langpair').css('display', 'inline-block');
}
else {
$('#langpair').css('display', 'none');
}
)};
    var options = {
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true,
        sourceLanguage: 'en',
        destinationLanguage: ['hi'],
      };
      var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
       control.makeTransliteratable(['message']);

      $("#langpair").change(function() {

        var data = this.value;

        var destinationLanguage = google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode[data];
        control.setLanguagePair('en', destinationLanguage);
      });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i set default language to 'English'. I tried to change sourceLanguage and destinationLanguage to other languages, and its working. But if destinationLanguage is set to 'en', then it shows error.

Comment: What is expected result of setting `destinationLanguage` property to value `['or']` at `options` object passed to `new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl()`?

Comment: It is just an example (converts English to Oriya) and need to change. So i changed it to 'en' for English. But its not working

Comment: Are you trying the code locally? Is jQuery defined?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on my local server. Is there any other js file required?

Comment: Is `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>` loading jQuery?
`

Comment: Yes.  all the script files working fine

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing because you cannot have source language and target language be the same. It doesn't make sense to transliterate from English to English. it is not a valid pair

The exact error is

> Unsupported sourceLanguage & targetLanguage pair: sourceLanguage: en targetLanguage: en

The default source language is english you do not have to set it. From official doc

> sourceLanguage is a mandatory string that specifies the source language using the LanguageCode enum (as in google.elements.transliteration.ENGLISH). Currently, English is the only supported source language.

And you are setting the ***destination language*** default only.So you have to  choose one Indian language as default in HTML you can do it by adding selected attribute to option tag.

```
<option selected >Tamil</option>
```

Comment: Thank you Shyam. Its working now. To switch between English and other languages, shortcutKey option is there.

Comment: But I need English as default language. Is it possible

Comment: I made some changes in my code. default language is set to Hindi as you suggested.  But now I have a dropdown for select either English or Unicode options. If I select Unicode then next dropdown with regional languages will appear. In this case I need to set English as my default option. Is it possible ?